# custom foreach with respective title

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

[image]

I have the loop here see the image for reference..

I have the column called Supplier Name

For example there are two row at the same supplier name

so i need the one heading

my expected ouptut is

**ABS Agencies**

Supplier name - here should be the heading

- ABS Agencies - **heading**

  2. ABS Agencies
  3. ABS Agencies

**mycode here**

```
   @foreach($prsdkgrids as $prsdkgrid)
                 <?php if($prsdkgrid->SupplierName == $prsdkgrid->SupplierName){ $SupplierName[] = $prsdkgrid->SupplierName; } ?>
                 @endforeach    

@foreach($prsdkgrids as $prsdkgrid)
                 <?php  if(count($SupplierName) == $SupplierName[$f]) { }else{  echo $f."<tr><td><h3 style='font-size: 15px;'>$prsdkgrid->SupplierName</h3></td></tr>"; } ?>
                 <tr class="psr_table1_tr" id="PSupdetID<?php echo $prsdkgrid->PSupdetID; ?>" <?php if($prsdkgrid->ApprovalStatus == 1){ echo 'style="background: #d9edf7;"';} ?>  >
                 <td> {{ Form::label('', $prsdkgrid->ArticleNo) }} </td>
                 <td> {{ Form::label('', $prsdkgrid->Size) }} </td>
                 <td> {{ Form::label('', $prsdkgrid->SpecialDesc) }} </td>
                 <td> {{ Form::label('', $prsdkgrid->QtyExp) }} </td>
                 <td> {{ Form::label('', $prsdkgrid->Coloring) }} </td>
                 <td> {{ Form::label('', $prsdkgrid->Packaging) }} </td>
                 <td> {{ Form::label('', $prsdkgrid->Packing) }} </td>
                 <td> {{ Form::label('', $prsdkgrid->TargetPrice) }} </td>
                 <td> {{ Form::label('', $prsdkgrid->SupPrice) }} </td>
                 <td> {{ Form::label('', $prsdkgrid->SupplierName) }}</td>
                 <td> {{ Form::label('', $prsdkgrid->SupComments) }} </td>
                 <td> <?php if($prsdkgrid->ApprovalStatus == 0){  ?><div align="center" class="floatleft approvedk" id="ApprvedbyResp<?php echo $prsdkgrid->PSupdetID; ?>">  
                 <li><a class="prs_add_link" href="#"><input class="save_btn Approve"  type="button" onclick="ApprvedbyResp(<?php echo $prsdkgrid->PSupdetID; ?>)" value="Approve"></a></li></div><?php } ?> </td>
                 </tr> <?php $f++; ?>
                 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the supplier_name in a variable and in the loop you can just compare the variable and supplier name. A simple approach is like this since you're using `foreach()`

```
$tmp_supplier_name = '';

foreach($prsdkgrids as $prsdkgrid){

  echo ($tmp_supplier_name != $prsdkgrid->supplier_name) ? '<tr>SUppliername</tr>' : ''; //compare

  $tmp_supplier_name = $prsdkgrid->supplier_name; //store the suppliername that was compared

}
```

Or another approach is try to manipulate your array and it should be something like this , much readable.

```
Array(
  ['supplierA'] =>
          Array(
             [0] => array(.....)
             [1] => array(.....)
          ),
  ['supplierB'] =>
         Array(
             [0] => array(.....)
             [1] => array(.....)
          )
)
```

Recreate the array example:

```
    $new_array = [];
    $tmp_supplier_name = '';

foreach($prsdkgrids as $prsdkgrid){

    if($tmp_supplier_name  != $prsdkgrid->supplier_name){
      $tmp_supplier_name = $prsdkgrid->supplier_name;
    }else{
      $new_array[$prsdkgrid->supplier_name]['opt1'] = $prsdkgrid->opt1;
      $new_array[$prsdkgrid->supplier_name]['opt2'] = $prsdkgrid->opt2;
      //and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i go with second option ?

Comment: @Glizzweb Please check the answer again